# Error while Getting data from an xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have written the following code to understand how php can be used to get and write data to xml files:

```
<?php

if (file_exists('/requests.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('requests.xml');
    foreach($xml->data->requests->request as $req)
    {
        print "Loop entered";
        print $req->ip;
        print $req->timelast;
    }
}
?>
```

The xml file requests.xml follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <requests>
    <request>
      <ip>6.6.6.6</ip>
      <timelast>2014-05-30 11:38:23</timelast>
    </request>  
   </requests>
</data>
```

The problem is that when the script is run, it does not display anything in the browser. In fact it does not enter the loop.

I'm definitely missing something basic.

Comment: add `print_r($xml);` and post output here

Comment: That was helpful in debugging. It wasnt entering the if file_exists loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml` will take your default node auto so no need to fetch result with data try

```
foreach($xml->requests->request as $req)
```

also change

```
if (file_exists('/requests.xml')) {
```

to

```
if (file_exists('requests.xml')) {  // if same dir
```

i have tried like:-

```
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <requests>
    <request>
      <ip>6.6.6.6</ip>
      <timelast>2014-05-30 11:38:23</timelast>
    </request>  
   </requests>
</data>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    foreach($xml->requests->request as $req)
    {
        print "Loop entered";
        print $req->ip;
        print $req->timelast;
    }
```

output :- `Loop entered6.6.6.62014-05-30 11:38:23`

Comment: you need to check you have if (file_exists('/requests.xml')) { or try to correct path

Comment: Thanks, @Rakesh Sharma. The issue was both the leading "/" and the default node. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try
{
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('requests.xml', null, true);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
foreach($feed->member as $property)
{
echo $property->id;
echo $property->lastName;
}
```

?>
  XML :
     
     
     1
     MSDWEr

Comment: <members>
  <member><id>1</id>
    <lastName>hello</lastName>
  </member>
 </members>